# Can you take a Javascript library and run it in Flash?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Lets say I pick up a pure Javascript library... one that doesn't rely on the DOM in any way.

Now, lets say I want to take that library and us it in Flex.  Is there any good way to do this?  I can't simply include the Javascript, as it is not close enough to ActionScript to compile... but is there a good converter that will do it for me?  Take the Javascript prototype style classes and convert it to ActionScript classes?

Lastly, I don't want to use the Browser for this.  I know that I can always use `ExternalInterface` to access the browser, but I am not always running my Flex app in the browser... sometimes it is Air, and sometimes it is in a PDF.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: No ideas on a converter, but JavaScript and ActionScript 3 share the same ECMA standard so theoretically, you could convert it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually porting from JS to AS isn't too hard.  But you might want to check out [Jangaroo](http://www.jangaroo.net/).  It goes the other direction, AS -> JS but might be able to be used in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

Why even bother? ActionScript already has util classes for things you might need to do, and most Javascript libraries are concerned with getting the DOM to behave. One of the nicest features of jQuery, for example, is the ability to address any element by its CSS selector. And you will never get that in ActionScript because it simply wouldn't make sense.

Maybe a better question is, what features of a Javascript library would you wish to see in ActionScript? Very likely there's already a class that does what you want, and if there isn't it's easy to create one.

Comment: Wow... I am a bit surprised to see your response get three up-votes... and someone with your rep on SO to give me as unhelpful of an answer such as "Why even bother?"  First of all, I asked the question for a reason... because I have a need.  I have a bunch of specific mathematics/set procedures for my domain that do not exist in ActionScript, Flash or Flex.  I want to re-use the code. Second, it is wrong to say that jQuery wouldn't make sense in AS3... at least in Flex, since it also supports CSS. See AS3Query -- http://drawlogic.com/2008/04/24/as3query-actionscript-port-of-jquery/

Comment: @Brian: With all due respect, if you had specified those specific needs you might have received a better answer. Second, if your Javascript libraries are mainly mathematical algorithms, then they should work with little or no change in AS3. Third, the Flex support for CSS is limited and AS3Query is itself limited, poorly documented, and in some ways incompatible with AS3 (problems with FlexBuilder, etc.). If it floats your boat, however, enjoy.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me what I was asking for... but no big whoop.  Anyways, There are many changes that need to be made to this JS to make it run in ActionScript... mostly due to the differences in the way classes are defined.  Not that I can't do the job by hand... it is relatively trivial... but if there were an automated process for this then sharing would be easier -- especially when changes get made to the JS code that need to be merged over... thats all.

Comment: +1 back up to 3. If you are not always running in a browser then why are you even bothering with JS in the first place? It seems to me there is a serious design flaw here

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the library you want to use it could be either trivial modification by adding a few required parameters (such as the package {} wrapper and so on). However, some of the transformations wouldn't be trivial and might require a full on compiler.

I do wonder how much work it would be to write a new backend for the [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/). Haven't looked into the source code of it, but I assume it is reasonably modular. That way the conversion would be automatic modulo the things that you can't do in AS3 such as DOM manipulation.

Even using this though you wouldn't get some of the nice things of AS3 such as compile time type checks. Also prototype to inheritance conversion is a non-trivial transformation, so you probably wouldn't get that either.